# Accessing base class method using generic T

Tags: c#, generics, base-class

I have this base class:

```
public class BaseEvent
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    public int GetEventID()
    {
        return EventID;
    }
}
```

And then I have another class inherited from that base one:

```
public class ValidationResult<T> where T : BaseEvent
{
    private void AddEventStatusUpdater(ValidationResult<T> validationResult)
    {
        validationResult.GetEventID();
    }
}
```

The issue I´m having is that I cannot access the GetEventID() method from the base class.

I think this may happen because I´m using a T generic. Is there any other way to access this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ValidationResult<T> where T : BaseEvent
```

Says that `T` must be a `BaseEvent`, not that `ValidationResult<T>` inherits from `BaseEvent`. That'd be:

```
public class ValidationResult<T> : BaseEvent
```

And there `T` would not have any constraint

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have begun to implement a generic interface rather than inheriting from the base class. I think you meant to do the following:

```
public class ValidationResult : BaseEvent
{
    private void AddEventStatusUpdater()
    {
        var id = this.GetEventID();
    }
}
```